# openVPN Mac(Tunnelblick) all traffic over VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, mac, traffic

The problem is that we want to use openVPN here as default VPN Server. Now we have the same problem like everytime. On Windows all works fine but on Mac we have problems with the routing.

When you are logged on to the network all your internet traffic goes through the VPN connection. We have set routes for this in the Serverconfig but they have no effect on the target system.

Is here anybody who have a solution for this?

thx for you help

**UPDATE:**

I don't want that the traffic goes through the VPN connection! The problem is when anybody download a file our connection here is dead.

Comment: I think you need to update your questions with specific examples from your configuration...e.g., your OpenVPN client configuration, the output of "netstat -rn" after the VPN connection is up, etc.

Comment: If you're using Tunnelblick, you might want to ask on the [Tunnelblick discussion group](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tunnelblick-discuss) Tunnelblick discussion group. If not, try the [OpenVPN user's mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.network.openvpn.user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this should be independent of which platform you run open-vpn on, you should be fine if you set the redirect-gateway directive on the Server.

See the  [openVPn howto](http://openvpn.net/howto.html) for further details.

## Update

In the question you told you set the routes. Setting the routes might or might not be the exact same thing as redirect-gateway. I can't tell without knowing your configuration. OpenVPN supports various ways to set routes according to the client system or specification.

You might also want to recheck if you've set the route-method and route-delay values.

Comment: I have written direct in the headline "MAC" the problem is only with MAC all other platforms run fine! We have tested the option "redirect-gateway" and nothing happen.

Answer (score 3):

I have OpenVPN running on OSX with Tunnelblick.

To get all the traffic go through the VPN connection, I added the following to my OpenVPN server's configuration:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

OpenVPN's (version 2.1) documentation defines "def1" as follows:

> def1 -- Use this flag to override the default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.

I have no other settings affecting the routing.

Comment: hmm i don't wont that the internet traffic goes through VPN. When anybody starts a download the internet connection is dead.

Comment: Then maybe you need to remove the redirect-gateway definition from configs.

Comment: Although this is not the answer to the above question this *IS* the answer for me. Perfect It's what I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation and researched it a bit. I've registered an [issue on TunnelBlick](https://github.com/Tunnelblick/Tunnelblick/issues/298).

The immediate workarounds are described in [OpenVPN wiki](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway). The method 2, `override`, looks the most simple.

> Add the following options to the clients config:

```
route 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 64.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 128.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 192.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** In Tunnelblick GUI there is option to do so without changing configuration:
[screenshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwQJk.png)

Tunnelblick version: Tunnelblick 3.8.7a (build 5770)